# Publish a WordPress Draft if it's title contains a specific phrase

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a wordpress plugin that will publish a draft only when the draft's title contains a certain keyword that I specify. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_post( $data , $postarr )
{
  if($data['post_title'] == 'something')
      $data['post_status'] = 'draft';

  return ( $data )
}

add_filter ( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post' , 99 );
```

Should work but didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_post( $data , $postarr ) {

    if (!preg_match("/\bsomething\b/i", $data['post_title']))
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';

    return ( $data );
}

add_filter ( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post' , '99', 2 );
```

If the word **something** doesn't appear in the tittle text, it becomes a draft, else, it publishes normally. Just change the keyword and it should work.